# Swift set default date to 10 years back

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I want to set the default date of picker view to 10 years back from current date. The code I have so far is this.

```
  let datePicker            = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    dateOfBirthTF.inputView   = datePicker

    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changed),
                         for: .valueChanged)
```

to get value change

```
func changed(datePicker:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter       = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    dateOfBirthTF.text = strDate
}
```

It sets the default date to current date perfectly but if I try to subtract a few years it doesn't work. Let me know the changes I need to do on this code to set the default date a few years back.

Comment: None of the code you posted is relevant to your question. Where's your attempt to calculate and set this 10-year old date on the date picker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get 10 years back date using these lines of code.

```
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let backDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: -10, to: Date())
    print("\(backDate)")
```

`-10` represent the number of years.

Comment: print() is log statement in Swift.

Comment: 'twoDaysAgo' was a writing mistake.

Answer (score 6):

```
datePicker.date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -10, to: Date())
```