# How do I set a datePicker's display to an AppStorage time (hour, min) settings?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, swiftui

I'm trying to allow the user to select what time they want a notification to go off through time selection on a datePicker. I have a datePicker set to only display the time as follows:

```
DatePicker("First Workout Notification Time", selection: $firstNotificationTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
```

I want the firstNotificationTime @State var to use my @AppStorage time vars which are set as defaults on this page above the "var body: some View" as:

```
@AppStorage("startNoficationHour") var startNoficationHour: Int = 9
@AppStorage("startNoficationMin") var startNoficationMin: Int = 30
```

When the view loads (i.e. .onAppear(){}) I want the datePicker's $firstNotificationTime to get set to the startNoficationHour and startNoficationMin

my view is set up as follows:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
DatePicker("First Workout Notification Time", selection: $firstNotificationTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
}
}
.onAppear(){
// set datePicker's fisrtNotificationTime to startNotificationHour and startNotificationMin
let components = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current, timeZone: TimeZone.current, hour:startNoficationHour, minute: startNoficationMin)
firstNotificationTime = components.date!        
                        print("start hour is \(startNoficationHour) and start minute is \(startNoficationMin)")
}
.onDisappear(){
// sets startNotificationHour and startNotificationMin to datePicker
                        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: firstNotificationTime)
                        startNoficationHour = components.hour!
                        startNoficationMin = components.minute!
                        print("start hour is set to \(startNoficationHour) and start minute is set to \(startNoficationMin)")
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60494166/set-default-date-on-datepicker-in-swiftui

Comment: Right, but I don't want to ADD to the current date, I just want to set it to a saved time. I've taken the code from that example and edited my question above. Because it's adding to the current date it's not working right. I guess I don't know the DateComponents well enough to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

ok so all I had to do was set a component variable to the hour and minute and place that in the onAppear

```
let components = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current, timeZone: TimeZone.current, hour:startNoficationHour, minute: startNoficationMin)
firstNotificationTime = components.date!
```

I updated my question above with the answer which was based on the comment from Tushar Sharma above that linked to this [Set default date on DatePicker in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60494166/set-default-date-on-datepicker-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing so much thing. There is easy solution. Use a shadow property.

`Date` has a method that convert the time into a double value. So, you can store the double value into `@AppStorage` and use it to update the date.

Here is an example,

Create a `@State` date variable,

`@State var reminderTime = Date()`

Create a show property save the date.

`@AppStorage("reminderTime") var reminderTimeShadow: Double = 0`

Now in the `DatePicker`,

```
 DatePicker("", selection: Binding(
                            get: {reminderTime}, set: {
                                reminderTimeShadow = $0.timeIntervalSince1970
                                reminderTime = $0
                                setNotification()
                            }), displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)   
                    .onAppear {
                        reminderTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: reminderTimeShadow)
                    }
```

Here, you use the explicit binding to get and set the value and when setting the value of reminderTime, you also set the value `reminderTimeShadow` and save it by `@AppStorage` and use this in `.onAppear` by using `reminderTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: reminderTimeShadow)` thus update `reminderTime` and the view.